# ORDER BY date ASC placing records with no dates before records with dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID";
$sql .= " WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'task'";
$sql .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_parent IN ( SELECT `ID` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type` = 'task_list' AND `post_parent` IN ( SELECT `ID` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'project' ) )";
$sql .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.post_id IN ( SELECT `post_id` FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_completed' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '0' )";
$sql .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.post_id IN ( SELECT `post_id` FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_assigned' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '%s' )";
$sql .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_due'";
$sql .= " GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID";
$sql .= " ORDER BY CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) ASC, $wpdb->posts.ID ASC";

$tasks = $wpdb->get_results( sprintf( $sql, $user_id ) );

return $tasks;
```

The result of the query is like this:

1. Post A.
2. Post B.
3. Post X. Due: August 2
4. Post Y. Due: August 3
5. Post Z. Due: August 4

Why are the posts with no `_due` value always returned first? How can I make it so they are always returned last? If I do this:

```
 $sql .= " ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID ASC, CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) ASC";
```

The posts with no `_due` value are randomly placed in between posts with `_due` value.

The ideal result should be:

1. Post X. Due: August 2
2. Post Y. Due: August 3
3. Post Z. Due: August 4
4. Post A.
5. Post B.

Thoughts?

Comment: Those without _due are considered as having due 0,so they come first.

Comment: What type is `postmeta.meta_value` and by no date, do you mean a `NULL` date?

Comment: so is this "Post X. Due" in seperate column and "August2" in different column?

Comment: @Jodrell: It's `longtext`. No it's not `NULL` but `empty` value. FYI, it's a Wordpress schema.

Comment: @AshReva: No. `Post X` is in a separate table called `wp_posts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"ORDER BY CASE WHEN CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) '' THEN 1 ELSE 0             
 END,CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE )ASC, $wpdb->posts.ID ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the function isnull to your order by clause:

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID ASC, ISNULL($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value),CAST( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value AS DATE ) ASC";
```

Comment: ISNULL is IFNULL in mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(_due, MAXDATE)
```

where MAXDATE is some future date higher than an _due value.